# iOS Swift Admob "Request Error: No ad to show." with test ad ID

Tags: ios, swift, admob

My app can not get the ads (also test ad id).
I'm using now test Ad Id (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716), and i research many things about this issue in google a few days, but no result about my case.
Can anyone please review and help me? Thanks!

**The error**

```
Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show.}
```

**Here is my Code (GAD SDK version is 10.4.0)**

AppDelegate

```
...
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ GADSimulatorID ]
...
```

Controller

```
...
        AdUtil.displayBannerAd(self)
...
```

AdUtil

```
...
    static func displayBannerAd(_ sender: UIViewController) {
        if (!AppSetting.shared.isRemovedAd) {
            GoogleAdHelper.shared.setBannerUID(Constant.ADMOB.BANNER_UID)
            GoogleAdHelper.shared.setBannerPosition(AdPosition.bottom)
            GoogleAdHelper.shared.displayBannerAd(sender)
        }
    }
...
```

GoogleAdHelper

```
...
    func displayBannerAd(_ sender: UIViewController) {
        LogUtil.debug("PBExtensionGoogleAd BannerUID \(bannerUID)")
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
        bannerView.adUnitID = bannerUID

        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.rootViewController = sender
        bannerView.tag = 99
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }
...
```

Constants

```
    struct ADMOB {
        static let BANNER_UID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        static let INTERSTITIAL_UID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5135589807"
        static let REWARD_UID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313"
    }
```

Comment: same error with Interstitial and Rewarded ad (test ID)

Comment: iOS 16.4.1, Real device iphone 13 prm, Simulator iphone 14 prm, GAD 10.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for reading!
I figured out it happened because my app bundle id (iOS) was limited by Google, so all ads were requested from this app bundle id will be limited.
When i create new bundle id and use that for this app, everything work fine!